# Mysql unknown column tablex.name

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to use this query, Without the JOIN clauses it work fine, so the tablex.index exist already

```
SELECT tablex.name , owner , hotspot.name 
FROM tablex, mysecondDB_hotspot AS hotspot 
LEFT JOIN roaming_groups ON roaming_groups.nas=tablex.name 
LEFT JOIN rates ON rates.rate=tablex.rate 
LEFT JOIN rates AS rates2 ON rates2.rate=tablex.rate2 
WHERE tablex.name="dLAN1310162210002353" and SUBSTR(tablex.name,5) = hotspot.hotspot_id
```

But I get error 1054 : unknown 'nases.name' in 'on clause'

Any idea ?

Comment: Comma joins are evaluated in a different order from explicit joins, but it's a simple rule to remember: Do not use comma joins. Ever. AND DEFINITELY DO NOT MIX THEM UP WITH OTHER JOINS (you will find examples here where I do - but I'm just lazy/showing off)

Comment: Could you please be more clear ? I dont get what you mean ?

Comment: OK, just as soon as you explain where `nases` comes from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing old-style and new-style joins.  Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.

Replacing it with a `CROSS JOIN` will fix your problem:

```
SELECT tablex.name , owner , hotspot.name 
FROM tablex CROSS JOIN
     mysecondDB_hotspot hotspot LEFT JOIN
     roaming_groups
     ON roaming_groups.na s= tablex.name LEFT JOIN 
     rates
     ON rates.rate=tablex.rate LEFT JOIN
     rates rates2
     ON rates2.rate = tablex.rate2 
WHERE tablex.name = 'dLAN1310162210002353; and
      SUBSTR(nases.name,5) = hotspot.hotspot_id
```

Note that your `WHERE` clause is turning your `LEFT JOIN`s into `INNER JOIN`s (although I have left the original join logic).

The problem is the use of `tablex` in the `ON` clause, not the `WHERE` clause.

Although the `,` is functionally equivalent to a `CROSS JOIN`, it is not semantically equivalent.  When using a comma, the parts before and after are parsed separately, so the second part does not recognize aliases from the first part.

Comment: Thank you, it works, I think I have to update my code style :) , I cant upvote you, no enough reputation xD